# Why are my child processes being waited on by parent without any work being done?

Tags: c, process, pipe, children, fork

I'm sure it's something fairly simple, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why my child processes are doing no work, getting waited on, then the last one is pausing (like I'm not closing the pipes properly).  At any rate, I'll post a bunch of code but this is what it's doing:

1. The program parses a txt document and takes all individual words, and sends them along a pipe round-robin style to a specified number of child processes.  I have a 1 dimensional array that holds the pipe FD's with every even index being a read, and every odd index being a write pipe.
2. After the parsing is finished, the program closes the read/write pipes prior to forking children (to close the pipes with the parent). Then, within a for loop, the specified number of child processes are spawned and the write end of the corresponding pipes are closed off in the child, and the read ends are opened.  fgets MUST be used to take the input from the pipes (I know, annoying, but it's a requirement).
3. After the child is done, it gets waited on by the parent process.  There are some comment and debugger lines that I've tried to get to help me, and from them it seems like the child processes are being forked and entered correctly, the write pipe is closed, the read pipe is opened, but when I do the fgets() function, it immediately exits and gets waited on by the parent.  Interestingly, not all children get waited on.  If I want the number of children to be 3, 2 processes are waited on, the 3rd gets hung up.  If I want 10 processes, 5 get waited on, and the 6th gets hung up.

So, I am pretty certain it has something to do with fgets() but I cannot figure out why!  I have a hunch it may be something to do with newline characters being in the wrong spot when they're sent along the pipe (fgets reads up until newline, right?) but based on the code written and some additional debugging statement the input into the pipe from the parent process seems to be newline terminated properly.

At any rate, here's the code for both the parser then the bit with creating the children --

Parser:

```
char buf[PIPE_BUF];     
int wordCount;

char buffer[PIPE_BUF];
char *temp;
char word[50];
FILE* inputFile = fopen(fileName,  "r"); //OPENS file
//Parsing and distributing words round robin to pipes
while(fgets(buffer, (sizeof buffer), inputFile)){
    //remove all non-alpha chars in buffer and converts to lowercase
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++){
        if(isalpha(buffer[i]) == 0){ //0 means it is not a letter
            buffer[i] = ' ';
        }
        else{
            buffer[i] = tolower(buffer[i]); //turn the current word to lower case
        }
    }
    //parse words and sends them to the sort processes in a round-robin fashion
    temp = strtok(buffer, " "); //splits along spaces
    if(temp != NULL){
        strcpy(word, temp);
        strcat(word, "\n"); //puts newline at the end
    }
    int j = 0;
    while(temp != NULL){
        FILE *input = fdopen(pipefds[(j*2)+1], "w");
        //close(pipefds[j*2]); //closing read pipes in parent
        fputs(word, input); //puts into write pipe
        printf("fputs done successfully with pipe %d with contents: %s\n", pipefds[(j*2)+1], word);
        //close(pipefds[(j*2)+1]); //closing write pipe after write is done
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if(temp != NULL){
            strcpy(word, temp);
            strcat(word, "\n");
        }
        if(j == (numChildren - 1)){
            j = 0;
        }
        else{
            j++;
        }
    }
}
//need to close all parent writes, and parent reads (it's done with everything)
for(i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){
    close(pipefds[i]);
}
```

Parent forking and getting piped data:

```
//Collection of children need to be created specified by numChildren
int count;
for(count = 0; count < numChildren; count++){
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);

    switch((p = fork())){

    case -1:
        perror("Could not create child");
        exit(-1);

    case 0:
        printf("Entering child\n");
        //child case, GET INPUT FROM PARENT TO SORT!!! SEND TO SUPPRESSOR (Uses both input and output)
        //count[0] = read, count[1] = write
        close(pipefds[(count*2)+1]); //closing write pipes in child
        printf("write pipe closed in child\n");
        FILE *output = fdopen(pipefds[count*2], "r"); //opening the read pipe from the parent write pipe
        printf("read pipe opened in child\n");
        fgets(buf, PIPE_BUF, output); //gets data from read pipe
        printf("child read pipe contents read (fgets) with buf contents: %s\n", buf);
        printf("child read pipe closed (%d)\n", getpid());
        //execlp("sort", "sort", sortStuff,(char*)NULL);
        close(pipefds[count*2]); //closing read pipe after reading is done
        count = numChildren;
        break;

    default:
        //parent case -- p holds pid of child

        printf("I am the parent, PID: %d\n", getpid());
        child = wait(&status);
        printf("Waited on child %d\n", child);

        break;
    }

}
```

I apologize in advance for the code, I'm not the best C programmer, so things tend to get a little messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is with this code:

```
// need to close all parent writes, 
// and parent reads (it's done with everything)

for(i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){
  close(pipefds[i]);
```

You do this (it appears) before you create the child processes, and by doing so, you basically remove the pipes.  They're gone.  They no longer exist.  There's nothing for the child process to read.  My guess is that this line:

```
FILE *output = fdopen(pipefds[count*2], "r");
```

is failing (output is NULL) because the file descriptor has already been closed, and thus, is an invalid descriptor as far as the system is concerned.

Another issue is the order of your steps.  Typically, you create a pipe, then create a child process and it's only after the child process is finished do you close out the pipe.  I don't think I've ever seen an implementation that writes to a pipe, *then* creates the child processes to read from it, since there is one large problem with this:  pipes are limited in size, and the parent process can block writing to a pipe (I suspect you have a small file you are testing against and thus, aren't hitting the size limit of the pipe).

The order of steps I would recommend is:

```
create the pipes
create the child processes
in the parent process
    close the read end of each pipe (only the read end)
    read the text file
    write words to the pipes
    when done reading text file, close the write end of each pipe
    wait for each child 
in the child process(es)
    close the write end of the pipe its using
    while there is input from the pipe
      read the input
      do whatever
    close the read end of the pipe
    _exit()
```

That way, you actually receive the benefit of multiprocessing and you won't have to worry about the parent indefinitely blocking when writing (because there's always a child process reading).

Comment: Aha thank you.  Just to be perfectly clear, you mean I should be creating the pipes before any forking, or for that matter the parsing, then fork, and under the switch statement default: case, I should do the tasks for the parent?  I was under the impression that you couldn't rely on the parent always running first.

Comment: You create the pipes, then fork.  The parent process reads the files and writes to the pipes; the child processes read from the pipes.  You don't need to worry about who runs first---reading from an empty pipe is a blocking operation.

Comment: Thank you.  My problems with this still aren't quite solved, but at least they're being piped (more or less) in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you associate a FILE* with the descriptors using this function:

FILE *input = fdopen(pipefds[(j*2)+1], "w");

then anything you do with *input is going to be buffered *in addition to* whatever buffering goes on in the pipe.  So it's possible that whatever you *think* you're writing to the pipe, is actually just sitting in the FILE*'s buffer and never actually reaching the pipe.  If you used fclose(input) the buffer would be flushed through at the end, but I think you're closing the underlying file descriptor, not the FILE*, which means all the buffer management for FILE* doesn't know it should finish up.

A call to fflush(input) might help.

Separately, and deeper still, if you're writing *all* your data to the pipe before you even start reading it, you should be aware that there is a limit to what the pipe can buffer before it won't accept any more input (until something is read out of the other end.)

EDIT:  Summary, I think you're data is stuck in the FILE* buffer and never even gets to the pipe.  Not flushed.  Also, you should probably be calling fclose(input) someplace, which will affect your need to close() the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: Seems fair, though I'm not sure where to put them.  I tried putting fflush(input) right after I declared input, and that didn't change anything.  should I do it after I've written to the pipe?  I can't do fclose(input) because I have to reuse the pipes so I can send the words round robin style, so when I tried fclose(input) in the parser it gave me a seg fault.

Comment: You should do the fflush() right after the fputs(), because it is the fputs call that puts bytes in the buffer, and you want to flush after you have those bytes.  You're still going to be leaking without the fclose(), but first things first :)

Comment: Alright that is certainly a step in the right direction.  It seems not all children are getting the piped text, but at least the last couple in every case are.  fflush was definately part of it.  I'm also going to try to fix up the piping issue that Sean Connor suggested